# Is there a way to specify the "Display Name" (or "File As") in the People Hub?

Tags: settings, contacts, people-hub

In desktop Outlook if you have an entry in your contact address book which is maybe just a first name and company name you can set the company name (or anything else) as the display name (actually on the screen this is called *File As*).

[image]

Can I do something similar in my Windows Phone **"People"**?

I've got an entry something like this:

```
First Name: Phil  
Surname: <left blank>
Company Name: Stack Exchange Inc  
Phone: 01234 567890
```

Which is currently getting filed under **P** whereas **S** would be more useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can sort by either first name or last name (surname). you can change this in the settings here:

settings -> applications -> people -> Sort list by: First name / Last name

you can also change the display name there to First,Last or Last,First

There is no "display name" or "file as" property on windows phone available so sorting by company name is not possible.

Comment: no, i'm leaving surname blank. i'm using the **company name** properly

Comment: On Windows Phone it's not possible to choose how to file the names as in outlook. the only way you can set this is by the way i described in my answer.. Didn't know you could do this with the "file as" using the company field. :)